# Characterization of complex or real coefficients polynomials

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, real-numbers

with integer coefficients, we can find polynomials by looking at the cyclotomic polynomials.

What are the general characteristics of complex number and real number coefficients polynomials which satisfy that $f(x)|f(x^2)$. Do we have some methods to count them or find them?

For example, $f(x)=(x-i)(x-1)(x+1)$satisfies this property. Also the $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of your [Find the polynomials which satisfy the condition $f(x)\mid f(x^2)\,$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128306/find-the-polynomials-which-satisfy-the-condition-fx-mid-fx2)?