# Polynomial $f(x)$ divides $f(x^2)$, how to generate all $f(x)$ of degree 3 and 4 efficiently?

Tags: polynomials

Suppose we have a monic polynomial $f(x)$. Given that $f(x)$ divides $f(x^2)$, is there an efficient way to generate a complete list of all such polynomials of degree 3 and 4?

My friend showed me this problem without the degree part, and I was able to easily find all such polynomials of degree 1 and 2 by letting $f(x)=x^2+px+q$ and $g(x)=x^2+rx+s$ where $f(x)g(x)=f(x^2)$, then equating coefficients on both sides of the equation. However, this method gets way too tedious for higher degrees so I'm asking if there is a more efficient way to find a *complete list* of these polynomials for degree 3 and 4.

I found a similar question on this site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128306/find-the-polynomials-which-satisfy-the-condition-fx-mid-fx2), but it focuses on getting polynomials with coefficients of certain types rather than by degree. The root method described in the second answer also seems to get too tedious and involve a lot of casework when we move to higher degrees.

List for degree 1:

- $x$
- $x-1$

List for degree 2:

- $x^2$
- $x^2-x$
- $x^2-1$
- $x^2+x+1$
- $x^2-2x+1$

Comment: What are the answers for degree $1$ and $2$?  Are there any examples besides $x^n(x-1)^m$?   I mean...you know that $f(\alpha)=0\implies f(\alpha^2)=0$ And you know that every root of $f(x)$ is also a root of $f(x^2)$ which looks like it should imply that only $0,1$ can be roots.  Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @lulu You are mistaken. E.G. $f(x) = x^2 + x +  1$ works.

Comment: @CalvinLin  Ok, thanks. So you can also have roots of unity as roots.  Perhaps a simpler example is $f(x)=x^n-1$ for any $n$ (yours is essentially $n=3$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can go after every such polynomial all at once. The key observation is that the condition $f(x)$ divides $f(x^2)$ is equivalent to the following condition (for an algebraically closed field):

> If $x$ is a root of $f$, then $x^2$ is also a root of $f$ with the same or greater multiplicity.

This is proven by completely factoring $f$ as $$f(x)=(x-r_1)^{a_1}(x-r_2)^{a_2}\ldots (x-r_k)^{a_k}$$ for distinct roots $r_i$ with multiplicities $a_i$. If we substitute in $x^2$ for $x$ and note $(x^2-k)=(x-\sqrt{k})(x+\sqrt{k})$ we get a complete factoring of $f^2$:
$$f(x^2)=(x-\sqrt{r_1})^{a_1}(x+\sqrt{r_1})^{a_1}(x-\sqrt{r_2})^{a_2}(x+\sqrt{r_2})^{a_2}\ldots (x-\sqrt{r_k})^{a_k}(x+\sqrt{r_k})^{a_k}$$
Note that since the original list of roots was distinct, this list of square roots is also distinct, except if $r_i$ was zero. Since these polynomials are completely factored, $f(x)$ divides $f(x^2)$ if and only if every term $(x-r)^a$ in the factorization of $f(x)$ appears in the factorization of $f(x^2)$ with *at least* the same multiplicity. Then, noting that the statement we want is trivially true if $x=0$, we are finished.*

We can then spin this into finding every possible such $f$: first, observe that if $x$ is a root, then the sequence $x,x^2,(x^2)^2, ((x^2)^2)^2,\ldots$ must be eventually periodic because all of these must be roots of $f$. This is equivalent to asking that $x$ either be $0$ or be a root of unity.

This can be used to computationally generate every possible polynomial (over $\mathbb C$ - or any field, for that matter) of each degree satisfying the given condition.

There turn out to be *a lot* of polynomials of this form - though note that every root must have that the sequence of squares $\{x,x^2,x^4,\ldots\}$ has size not exceeding the degree of the polynomial, which ensures that these lists are *finite* for each degree. For linear terms, you get
$$f(x)=x$$
$$f(x)=x-1$$
Since only $1$ and $0$ can be roots. Then, for quadratic terms, you get, letting $\gamma_{a,n}=e^{2\pi i a/n}$ be a root of unity:
$$f(x)=x^2$$
$$f(x)=x(x-1)=x^2-x$$
$$f(x)=(x-1)^2=x^2-2x+1$$
$$f(x)=(x-1)(x+1)=x^2-1$$
$$f(x)=(x-\gamma_{1,3})(x-\gamma_{2,3})=x^2+x+1$$
For cubic terms, I'll just list a few of the interesting ones, because you can start combining roots from previous "generations" in numerous uninteresting ways -- note, for instance, that we could take *any* of the quadratic polynomials, take a square root of any of their roots, and add that as a new root, which would give, already, quite a long list! You could also, multiply any of them by $x$ or $x-1$ to get another example. If we want to look at the "primitive" polynomials which are not divisible by any polynomial in a previous generation, you get the following conjugate pair (neither of which are polynomials over $\mathbb R$):
$$f(x)=(x-\gamma_{1,7})(x-\gamma_{2,7})(x-\gamma_{4,7})$$
$$f(x)=(x-\gamma_{3,7})(x-\gamma_{6,7})(x-\gamma_{5,7})$$
For fourth degree, you can expand the list of cubics, similarly. For degree $4$, you get a new real polynomial (which is a cyclotomic polynomial, not coincidentally) and two new complex ones:
$$f(x)=(x-\gamma_{1,5})(x-\gamma_{2,5})(x-\gamma_{4,5})(x-\gamma_{3,5})=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$$
$$f(x)=(x-\gamma_{1,15})(x-\gamma_{2,15})(x-\gamma_{4,15})(x-\gamma_{8,15})$$
$$f(x)=(x-\gamma_{14,15})(x-\gamma_{13,15})(x-\gamma_{11,15})(x-\gamma_{7,15})$$

I'm fairly sure that you'll get the complete list of polynomials of degree $n$ recursively as follows:

- Take the product of any two polynomials already found whose degrees sum to $n$.
- Take any polynomial $f$ found in the previous generation and some $r$ such that $r^2$ is a root of $f$ of greater multiplicity than the multiplicity of $r$ (which may be $0$). Multiply $f$ by $(x-r)$.
- Let $r$ be a value satisfying $r^{2^n}=r$ and such that no $n'<n$ satisfies this. Take the polynomial $(x-r)(x-r^2)(x-r^4)\ldots(x-r^{2^{n-1}})$.

though I haven't formally examined this. Note that I've only listed the final case for degrees $3$ and $4$ because the first and second cases are extremely numerous.

---

A stronger statement

> If $r$ is a root of $f(x)$ of multiplicity $a$, and a root of $g(x)-g(r)$ of multiplicity $b$ then $g(r)$ is also a root of $f(x)$ of multiplicity $c$ such that $bc \geq a$.

characterizes solutions to $f | f\circ g$, proved by similar means and gives similar results for how to list such polynomials.