# Find the polynomials which satisfy the condition $f(x) \mid f(x^2)$ called the factor square property

Tags: polynomials

The *Factor Square Property* (FSP) is the divisibility of the polynomial $f(x^2)$ by $f(x)$.

1. Is $x^2+x+1$ the only FSP irreducible polynomial of degree $2$ ?
2. Are there other linear polynomial besides $x$ and $x-1$ with FSP?
3. Do we have other FSP irreducible polynomials of degree $3$ or $4$? Any of these have integer coefficients??
4. **Are there any other observations you can make about polynomials with FSP?**

So this question has been posted before in:
[Link 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342070/factor-square-property-fsp-of-polynomials)
[Link 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128306/find-the-polynomials-which-satisfy-the-condition-fx-mid-fx2)

But the solutions use cyclotomic polynomials. 
Is there an easier solution? The Question is from Ross MathCamp, so, I suppose they will give some observation based question which doesn't require any kind of Complex Numbers I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Assuming that $f(x)$ is a monic and non-constant polynomial, $f(x)\mid f(x^2)$ implies that all the complex roots of $f(x)$ are roots of $f(x^2)$ too, hence that the set of roots of $f(x)$ is closed with respect to squaring. By considering the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial with $n$ being odd, we always have that $\Phi_n(x)$ is a divisor of $\Phi_n(x^2)$, hence there are polynomials with the FSP with arbitrarily large degree (the degree of $\Phi_n(x)$ is $\varphi(n)$).

Comment: I don't know about cyclotomic polynomials. I shall learn it but is there any other way? Geeky Ross doesn't give problems which require​ complex numbers and stuffs. They often give problems which are observation based.

Comment: @Mathbg: I guess there are many "naive" approaches to this problem, but I would raise a point. What is the purpose in avoiding the fundamental theorem of Algebra when studying Algebra?

Comment: Sir, I learnt about cyclotomic polynomials and I don't find any more naive approach than to use this. But since the admission test for Ross Camp generally requires naive approaches, I am just inquisitive about hearing such a solution.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I follow your answer, except why does n have to be odd when considering the nth the cyclotomic polynomial?

Comment: @TreFox: otherwise $\Phi_n(x)\mid \Phi_n(x^2)$ is not granted. For instance $\Phi_4(x)=x^2+1$ is not a divisor of $x^4+1$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio That makes sense, but how can I prove it for all even-numbered cyclotomic polynomials?

Comment: You cannot. $\Phi_{2m}(x)$ is not a divisor of $\Phi_{2m}(x^2)$ (it is enough to consider where the roots of these polynomials lie).

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Sorry! I think you misunderstood me. How can I prove that $\Phi_{2n}(x)$ is not a divisor of $\Phi_{2n}(x^2)$ for all $n$?

Comment: @TreFox: by comparing the roots.