# reducible Factor square polynomials(FSP) of degree 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I have a hard time looking for all degree 3 FSPs(By factor square polynomials I mean [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/342070/factor-square-property-fsp-of-polynomials)) because I found even though I am able to classify irriducible FSPs of degree 3, some other tricky reducible ones, like $x^3-1$, are reducible but cannot be expressed as a product of degree 1 FSP.

**So How can I give a list of all degree 3 and 4 FSP?**

Comment: Answerers: Please observe that this is from [an on-going contest](https://cpb-us-west-2-juc1ugur1qwqqqo4.stackpathdns.com/u.osu.edu/dist/e/5164/files/2018/01/App-Problems-2018-rog1cw.pdf). Deadline is apparently April 1st.